# Getting cdf content from nice Wolfram info graphic

Tags: cdf-format

There is a very nice cdf info graphic on the Wolfram Webpage (http://www.wolfram.com/cdf/uses-examples/infographics-full-example.html). I'd like to have a look at the code as I'd like to do something similar. However, they only provide the cdf. Is it possible to extract the code from this? – Thanks.

Comment: I have mailed and asked for the code, then the support mailed it. Don't know if this is true for this example, though.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: @MockupDungeon, and what is the result of your request to Wolfram support?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to download the *UnderstandingEarthquakes.cdf" with a software such http://www.httrack.com/, after about three minutes you will find the *.cdf in the follow directory:

projectname\www.wolfram.com\cdf\uses-examples

try to open "UnderstandingEarthquakes.cdf" with a program such as Notepad++.

I hope you can find the information you need.

**Edit**
To restore full `.nb`, copy Notepad++ or Sublime text of `.cdf` to clipboard and paste it into new notebook in the Row-input mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>). Go back to the notebook mode with the same combination. Then, in spite of the red error rectangle in the first row, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> and the desired result should appear (you may use `InputForm` to see its content in readable details).

Comment: I can download the cdf, I just can't access the code behind it.

Comment: @MockupDungeon ok and opening the file *. Cdf with a software like _Notepad++_ can not find anything interesting in the code visible?

Comment: You are right that I can then look into the file, however, all the commands are in their 'raw' form, which makes the code highly complex. So not really useful, although a nice workaround.

Comment: @MockupDungeon ok at the moment I have no other ideas. If it can be useful, copying part of the code in a spreadsheet _Mathematica_ _"*.nb"_ .You can see it through highlighting.